# How to Print the contents of a textbox in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-c++, printing, c++-cli

I'm having troubles getting say ResultsBox->Text to printer successfully. 
What is the proper way to print in C++/CLI?

I think im missing something simple.

Ive tried multiple different routes/syntax's that ive read online/ in books.
All of which got me to a dead end.

Please even a rundown on the method of printing in any C based language might point me the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Console::WriteLine(ResultsBox->Text);

Answer (score -1):

Are you using windows or a unix system?  It would be different for each printer, there is no generic print command, you would have to talk to the driver (or use the OS printing service).  If you are using windows you could use their print server but you would have to import a bunch of win dlls, and it wouldn't work on other systems.

I would recommend checking out cups http://www.cups.org/.  You can use IPP internet printing protocol and a socket library to print your stuff up.

Comment: C++/CLI is C++ on .NET on Windows. CUPS has no relevance, and you should tell him about Windows printing APIs.